# Xuggler for Linux

Tags: linux, video, video-processing, xuggler

I am trying to configure Xuggler on my Linux machine by following this tutorial: http://blog.xuggle.com/2009/01/23/how-to-install-xuggler-on-linux/ 
In one step it says "Download the latest Xuggler .tar.gz file for Linux from here" but i dont see any file or link there. Can someone please share the link from where I can download xuggler.tar.gz? I tried google but could not find anything.
Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That post is pretty old, and refers to the older versions of Xuggler where you had to actually install it. 
There's a "no-install" version now (since 5.2 or 5.3), and you can download the JAR files [here](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/).
Just download the one for the architecture of Linux you are using and add it to your project and you should be good!

Comment: You can also compile it for your machine.

Comment: That's true too. But it's definitely easier to use the pre-built ones if possible, since the process of compiling it yourself is pretty complicated.